# React-JS change state of a component by pressing on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I use Semantic-ui in my react-JS project, and I have some form inputs and a submit button there, these forms have a `prop` named `error`, and the value to this prop is given by state

The problem is that when I press on button, I trigger a function which should change the state which is assigned to this error prop from false to true, via setState, but it doesn't. But, when I type something in the input, the prop is changed by triggering `onChange` prop.

The button which I'm referring to is labeled `Next`

Here's some code :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: {
            firstName: false
        },
        general: {
            adminFirstName: "",
        },
    };
}
setData = () => {
    const {general} = this.state;
    const isValid = Object.keys(general)
        .filter( key => general[key].length !== 0 ).length === Object.keys(general).length;
    if (!isValid) { 
        Object.keys(general).map(key => { 
            if (general[key].length === 0) { this.setError(key); } });
    } else {
        // this.props.setGeneralData(general);
        // this.props.nextStep();
    }
    console.log(isValid);
    console.log(general);
};
setError = key => {
    const { error } = this.state;
    console.log(key);
    switch (key) {
    case "adminFirstName": {
        this.setState({ error: { ...error, firstName: true } });
    }
    default:
        this.setState({ error: { ...error } });
    }
};
render() {
    const { error, general } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="block--part_75">
            <Form>
            {/* First name */}
                <Form.Field required error={error.firstName}>
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <Input onChange={e => {
                        e.target.value.length !== 0 
                            ? this.setState({ 
                                error: { ...error, firstName: false },
                                general: {
                                    ...general,
                                    adminFirstName: e.target.value
                                }
                            })
                            : this.setState({
                                error: { ...error, firstName: true },
                                general: {
                                    ...general,
                                    adminFirstName: e.target.value
                                }
                            });
                        }}
                    placeholder="First name"
                    type="text"
                    />
                </Form.Field>
            {/* First name */}
            </Form>
            <Button onClick={this.setData} floated="right">
                Next
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear. Had the `setError` function called but the `state` hasn't been changed, or the `setError` even hasn't been called?

Comment: The `setError` function is called, but the `state` isn't changed

Comment: What type of component do you use? Is it a `PureComponent`?

Comment: Nope, It's just `Component`

Comment: How do you define, that the state hasn't been changed?

Comment: The `Form.Field` element has an `error` prop, if it's value is true, than it should turn red, but it doesn't, that's why I think that it isn't changing

Comment: Also, I typed there a `console.log` which shows the state after `setState` and it still remains at the same value - `false`

Comment: I found the problem. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding before setState, a variable, which will keeps the changes of the state you want to modify, and after just perform set state adding this variable, insted the object which you are additioning.

Here is a small example :

```
let changes = {...this.state.element, change};
this.SetState({data: changes});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot the `break` operator in the `switch`:

```js
setError = key => {
    const { error } = this.state;
    console.log(key);
    switch (key) {
        case "adminFirstName":
            this.setState({ error: { ...error, firstName: true } });
            break;
        default:
            this.setState({ error: { ...error } });
    }
};
```

Comment: Tried this, but still, same thing the state is `false` instead of `true` =/

Comment: Also, I've type in default, instead of `setState` a simple break, but it doesn't resolved my problem properly, In my original script I have 3 Form fields, and the state remains true only on the last one

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Maksimov's answer. I have replicated your problem on codesandbox, adding a break statement works properly.

Also, setState is async, so your `console.log()` after setState doesn't guarantee you the new state. I have `console.log` the result using setState callback and the firstName property is set to true.

[link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5z65z10okk)

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use this.setState to be able to trigger state changes. IF you directly set data to State properties it doesn't trigger the updates.

Comment: I'm using `setState`, that's the problem =/

Comment: @Eugen-AndreiColiban, sorry just to clarify are you speaking about this button ?<Button onClick={this.setData}  .../>

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about this one

Comment: @Eugen-AndreiColiban, oh I see. Are you sure that an appropriate case "adminFirstName" from setError switch is executed? Otherwise your code looks correct and it must set state.

Comment: @Eugen-AndreiColiban, and "this" from setError function is pointed to the correct component instance?

Comment: @Eugen-AndreiColiban, looks like Maksimov is right. :)